# SQL - call aggregate function in sort order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a custom aggregate function that concatenates items with a delimiter.
How can I call this function to ensure that the result is a sorted list.

Aggregate functions like sum() will have the same result no matter which order the rows are fed to it.

I can't easily sort the items in the aggregate function itself because the sort order depends on a different field.

For example:

```
product|size_id   | size_string
--------------------------------
prod1  |10        | x-small
prod1  |20        | small
prod1  |30        | medium
prod1  |40        | large
prod1  |50        | x-large
```

I would like a query to return:

> prod1, available in:
>   x-small,small,medium,large,x-large

I.e. in the sizes concatenated in the order of (size_id)

```
SELECT product,concat_agg(size_string) GROUP BY product;
```

will return the required data, but not in sorted order.

At the moment I'm using a function to cycle through the sizes in the correct order and adding them to the result. I suspect there might be an SQL way to have a subquery produce the desired result. There must be other aggregate functions that are not commutative.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699403/can-i-sort-data-for-an-aggregate-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an order by to the `GROUP_CONCAT` function (under MySQL:

```
SELECT product, GROUP_CONCAT(size_string ORDER BY size_id SEPERATOR ',')
GROUP BY product
```

Here is the [official help](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: I didn't know GROUP_CONCAT had ORDER BY. Thanks for this!

Comment: Actually I'm using postgres, which doesn't have GROUP_CONCAT but has an "array" feature which can be used in a similar way. Thanks for putting me on the right track. 
BTW should probably be "ORDER BY size_id"