# Can I sort data for an aggregate function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a custom CLR aggregate function. This function concats strings within a group. Now the question is, can I make this function process the data in some specific order or will it always be some random order the DB found suitable? I understand that for most mathematical aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, AVG etc.) it makes no difference in which order the data is processed, but let's say I want to concat strings alphabetically within a group is there something I can do to achieve this result?

Note that it **has** to be an aggregate function (don't get mislead by the examples below) <strike>and that altering the existing CLR function is out of question (all it does is a basic string concat and nothing more)</strike>.

I tested adding `ORDER BY` to the `SELECT` that contains the `GROUP BY`, but it produced no meaningful results.

```
SELECT
    user.Id, dbo.concat(cat.Name)
FROM
    Users user
    JOIN Cats cat ON (cat.Owner = user.Id)
GROUP BY user.Id
ORDER BY user.Id, MAX(cat.Name) --kind of meaningless really
```

I also tried to `ORDER BY` the table that contains the data which I want to concat before doing a `JOIN`, but the result was the same.

```
SELECT
    user.Id, dbo.concat(cat.Name)
FROM
    Users user
    JOIN (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT /*hack*/ c.* FROM Cats c ORDER BY c.Name) cat ON (cat.Owner = user.Id)
GROUP BY user.Id
```

Ordering data in a subquery and then doing a `GROUP BY` didn't work either.

```
SELECT
    t1.Id, dbo.concat(t1.Name)
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT /*hack*/
        user.Id, cat.Name
    FROM
        Users user
        JOIN Cats cat ON (cat.Owner = user.Id)
    ORDER BY user.Id, cat.Name
) t1
GROUP BY t1.Id
```

I was kind of expecting that neither of those will work, but at least now no one can say I haven't tried anything.

P.S. Yes, I have reasons not to use `FOR XML PATH`. If what I'm asking here cannot be done, I'll live with it.

Comment: Would adding DISTINCT help? dbo.concat(DISTINCT cat.Name)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas No, at least not in my case. To be honest, I'm actually sorting, by a number (and descending by that). So even if `DISTINCT` has a sorting side effect (does it have one?), it wouldn't help in my case.

Comment: It does have one :) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178401%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Maybe it would be possible to add sort option to your CLR aggregate?

Comment: Looks like the answer is no, it's under consideration for a future version of SQL Server: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/611026/add-support-for-over-order-by-for-clr-aggregate-functions

Comment: @ZoffDino You could have posted that as an answer. I also found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqluserdefinedaggregateattribute.isinvarianttoorder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. There is a flag that can indicate whether the rows need to be ordered or not (IsInvariantToOrder), but currently it's unused. The default value of this flag is false (which translates to actually using ordered data), but even so the data processed by the aggregate will not be ordered.

Comment: Consider the functions that a CLR aggregate has to [implement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131051.aspx). There can be multiple *instances* of the class each being passed a subset of the rows and then multiple `Merge` stages to reduce down to one before the final `Terminate`. You don't get control over what order those merges happen in nor which instance ends up being the final one used for output.

Comment: @jahu, you have to sort within CLR function. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out, usually in the `Terminate` phase. The data comes from the server into the function in an undefined (aka random) order, but once the function gets to the final phase it has all the elements and can sort them. See http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/ for the reference implementation. It has several variants with various sorting options.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov What you wrote sounds worth investigating (I need to make sure if I can sort data within the aggregate based on another column). However, this will have to wait till a later date as time allocated for the task which inspired the question has run out. Another thing I'll have to check is, if I can make a CLR aggregate return data as text or nvarchar(MAX) rather than nvarchar(4000) (I remember having some trouble with this in both CLR functions and normal stored functions and procedures).

Comment: @jahu, it is definitely possible to make CLR function that returns `nvarchar(max)`. I wrote my implementation for SQL Server 2008 inspired by [groupconcat.codeplex.com](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com) and it returns `nvarchar(max)`. To sort the result based on another column make a function that accepts two parameters: string value itself and the ordering key. Store all these key-value pairs inside the function in some dictionary sorted by key and build the final string in the `Terminate` phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information from Damien_The_Unbeliever, Vladimir Baranov, Microsoft pages and from few other users (see comments to the question), I can deduce that:

- Ordering rows for aggregate function cannot be done directly in the database; However there are hints that this is\might have been a planned feature (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqluserdefinedaggregateattribute.isinvarianttoorder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/611026/add-support-for-over-order-by-for-clr-aggregate-functions)); If MS ever implements this, some existing CLR aggregate functions might start acting weird (as by default those aggregate functions are flagged to be dependent on order)
- Ordering has to be implemented directly in the CLR function; It can be a little tricky [due to how CLR aggregate functions are being run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131051.aspx), but it can be done

Unfortunately I don't have a piece of code to present here, as I didn't had time to alter my CLR function (and doing unordered concat was good enough in my case).

Answer (score -2):

You can include a function in the order by clause.

try it with this dummy date returner:

```
create function testDate ()
returns datetime
as
begin
    declare @returnDate datetime
    select @returnDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    return @returnDate
end
```

run the function with any table (replace SomeTable with a real table) and order by it:

```
select  dbo.testDate (),
        *
from    SomeTable
order by dbo.testDate () desc
```

@jahu
EDIT: I thought you wanted to order by a user defined function.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question.  You can order a query by an aggregate function like this:

```
select  CustomerID,
        avg(OrderID)
from    Orders
group by CustomerID 
order by avg(OrderID) desc
```

The table above has OrderID as a unique column and there can be multiple CustomerID records

Comment: How would this dummy function make it work any better than then the actual column by which I want the data to be sorted (it work anyway, see potential reasons mentioned in the comments to the question)? I don't quite see how this answer relates to the question.

Comment: I wanted the aggregate function to process the data in certain order rather than order by result of an aggregate function, so I'm afraid your answer does not answer the question. So far there seem to be 2 answers to the problem put in the comments. 1) It cannot be done out of the box (kind of what I wanted to do) 2) I would have to implement it directly inside the CLR aggregate function (doable, but the client isn't paying enough to get it done ;).

Comment: If you need to process data in a certain order, you can use a cursor.  They have performance issues which might or might not matter depending the environment.  Since you have a small number of rows and since your process already is 30 seconds (I think you said that...), then it's worth a shot.

Comment: I don't remember writing anything about the number of rows or the time it takes to process them... I think you're confusing my question with the other one which you answered.